Azure pipeline stopped producing installable MAUI app
We have an Azure pipeline which builds and sign a MAUI app, then uploads to Dropbox from where we can download it and install it to phones. It was working fine until at some point the app stopped installing and now every Android device just says "can't install application".
My first thought was that maybe we had some certificate which has expired and needed renewal but after reviewing the YAML file for the pipeline I can see no certificate being used. I'm confused as to what broke.
The YAML file:
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- main

variables:
    BuildConfiguration: Release
    DotNetVersion: 8.0.100
    VSVERSION: 17/pre

stages:
- stage: BuildAndroid
  jobs:
  - job: BuildMAUIApps
    displayName: Build MyApp
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-2022'
      demands:
      - MSBuild
      
    steps:
    
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: .NET Version
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '$(DotNetVersion)'
    
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Install MAUI
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          dotnet nuget locals all --clear 
          dotnet workload install maui --source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet7/nuget/v3/index.json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
          dotnet workload install android maui wasm-tools --source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet7/nuget/v3/index.json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Restore nuget
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          cd src
          dotnet restore MyApp.sln
    
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Run tests
      inputs:
        command: 'test'
        projects: 'src\MyApp.sln'


    # https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/overview
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Build Android app
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          cd src
          dotnet build MyApp.sln -c Release

    # Signing Android App : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/mobile/app-signing?view=azure-devops&tabs=apple-install-during-build#sign-your-android-app

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        Contents: 'src\MyApp\bin\Release\net8.0-android\*.apk'
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        CleanTargetFolder: true
        OverWrite: true
        flattenFolders: true
    
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: Rename apk
      inputs:
        script: 'REN $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\com.mydomain.MyApp.apk MyApp.apk'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop_android'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
    - task: ZipAndDropBox@0
      displayName: ZipAndDropBox
      inputs:
        sourceDir: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        zipPath: '/company/MyApp_Droid.zip'
    - task: SendGridEmail@2
      inputs:
        SendGridApiKey: '$(SendGridToken)'
        FromAddress: 'val@mydomain.com'
        ToAddresses: 'val@mydomain.com,tester@mydomain.com'
        Subject: 'New version of MyApp'
        emailBodyFormat: 'InLine'
        EmailBody: |
          The new version is here: 
          
          https://www.dropbox.com/pathtofile
          


It's hard to know the problem without having the error messages.
Try to compare the last successful build and the build that is not working.
In case this would help.
I had a similar issue a couple of days ago when building an ios app.
I realized that the problem resides in the step installing MAUI.
Azure pipeline was using a different sdk which was causing the problem.
I had to add --from-rollback-file
dotnet workload install maui --from-rollback-file MauiJson.json
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/16600319/alvin-zhao-msft
I was able to fix the issue with the installable MAUI app on azure devops.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78076656/azure-devops-pipeline-rollback-file-for-net-maui-install-fails-with-is-an-i

  parameters:
  - name: MauiJson
    type: object
    default:
      microsoft.net.sdk.ios: 17.5.8021/8.0.101
      microsoft.net.sdk.maui : 8.0.81/8.0.101
      microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst : 17.5.8021/8.0.101
      microsoft.net.sdk.macos : 14.5.8021/8.0.101
      microsoft.net.sdk.android : 34.0.130/8.0.101

    variables:
    - name : 'MauiJson'
      value : ${{ convertToJson(parameters.MauiJson) }}

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Install MAUI
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          cat MauiJson.json
          dotnet nuget locals all --clear
          dotnet workload install maui --from-rollback-file MauiJson.json --source

https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet8/nuget/v3/index.json
--source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

